# How can i remove this anchor : hover tag problem

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am new to CSS, I just imported one theme (Shopping cart) in WordPress,I am getting the below error [image] ,

Whenever I bring my mouse hover to any hyperlink,a gray-box started visible and after 5,6 second it goes off. It is happening on each hyperlink on my website.

I have tried to check in each `a:hover { ...}` case, and tried with the content, but no success, I have uploaded my style.css , can anyone tell me the problem

File URL - https://easyupload.io/d2bcrx

Site is :- http://www.sadhagi.com

Error GIF

[image]

Thanks

As advised -

1) I am using Shopping cart theme from themefreesia (https://themefreesia.com/themes/shoppingcart/)

2) I used one click demo import plugin to import demo content

All went well, no error displayed at the time of installation of theme, was showing successfully installed.

Comment: please either share you code here directly in question or make a fiddle

Comment: i dont see it on your site, try cache clean use ctrl+f5 to reload page

Comment: its there, just go to any hyperlink and stay for 2,3 second.. and style.css is of 5048 lines of code

Comment: It does not seem to be appearing on the real site.

Comment: no still not, try in incognito mode of chrome,

Comment: @AhmedSunny and Shane - Pl check, I have added GIF of the error.. i tried in Incognito mode, still same error, even i tried in different browsers also, same error

Comment: its a tooltip issue, on chrome i dont get it, but on edge i got it. if you have title attribute in your element, it will automatically trigger tooltip
and becuase for the links title=" " is like this, with a space, thats why its showing like this

Comment: remove the space from title, or just remove the title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have title with space, title is use for tooltips,  chrome has default white background, edge has grey background. etc

to fix it either add some text, or remove space, or just remove title

[image]

Comment: You are absolutely correct !! Thanks dear.. Saved many hours.. :)

Comment: it seems many other have the same issue, you should add wordpress theme name and link or plugin you using in your question, and also add wordpress tag